# How to download from Dropbox and upload to Amazon s3 using Carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, dropbox

I am trying to figure out the best way to download a file from Dropbox and upload it to Amazon s3 using carrierwave.

Can use the Dropbox Chooser?  Or do I have to use the Core API from dropbox to get the file?

If I can do it through just the Chooser app, then how do I pass that file into Amazon s3?  Do I even need carrierwave?